# Show loading indicator in Angular while waiting for a RxJS observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular component that listens for a route parameter for a user id to change and when it does it loads the user details. The user details takes a few seconds to return data from the API.

If i'm viewing details for User A and then click to view details on User B, it continues to show User A until User B details are returned a few seconds after my click. Is there a way I can show a loading indicator or just blank it out while it's retrieving data for User B?

User details component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userDetails = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.userService.getUserDetails(+params.get('userId')))
  );
}
```

User details template:

```
<div *ngIf="userDetails | async as userDetails">
  <h1>{{userDetails.firstName}} {{userDetails.lastName}}</h1>
</div>
```

I would like the user details div to either be blank or show some sort of loading indicator if that inner switchMap is currently running. I know one option would be to have a loading variable that I set to true before the switchMap and false after the switchMap and use that in the *ngIf of the div, but I'm hoping there was a slicker way to not have to have loading variables for EVERY one of these situations.

I have an example StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-busy-yxo1gu

The goal is when I click the User B button, User A information should disappear while User B is loading. I have dozens of this scenario in my app so I'm looking for the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want the content to disappear you can emit for example `null` when you start fetching a different user:

```
this.userDetails = this.userId.asObservable().pipe(
  switchMap(id => merge(
    of(null),
    this.getUserDetails(id)
  )),
);
```

The `merge` Observable creation method will reemit emit `null` and then wait until `getUserDetails` completes. You don't even need `ng-busy` for this.

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-busy-vwteyf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 10):

you can change your *ngIf

```
ngIf="userDetails | async as userDetails else #loading"
```

then

```
<div #loading>
  loading...
</div>
```

[Reference](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable)

Comment: This works for loading the first user. But when I click on a different user it continues to show the first user's information until the new user has finished loading since the component is reused.

Comment: if you assign `this.userDetails = null` before you start async operation, it will be undefined that moment,  so it falls to else block

Comment: I get this error in my template: Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 76

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb this might help beginners, so I decided to add this comment, Angular `ngIf` directive else block only expects the template name, so you cannot place `#` here with the template name. it should be ```ngIf="userDetails | async as userDetails else loading" ```, Also I think you should use `<ng-template #loading>...</ng-template>` to setup your loading block in html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ng-busy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-busy) (or basically any other npm component out there) for displaying a loading indicator in each http call (promise or observable in your case) in your app.

**EDIT**: Regarding the fact that you're using Observable, you can use [.toPromise](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) in order to work with ng-Busy. Modified the DEMO to show you how to do that.

Here is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-53767697) of ng-busy with your code.

Comment: That's pretty close, but my userDetails is an observable. I took your stackblitz and modified it closer to what I have with userDetails. I have dozens of this scenario throughout my app so I'm looking for the slickest way to remove User A details after the user clicks on the User B button.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-busy-yxo1gu

Comment: @Jeremy did you see the updated DEMO? did it help you?

Answer (score 2):

Try my own library [ngrx-busy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-busy) to display loading indicator with any observables. Unlike the `ng-busy` library you don't need to cast it to Promises or store Subscription. Also you don't need to care about change detection strategy.

Just register the library single time (add Http interceptor and NgrxModule) and use it like this:

```
<ngrx-busy>
  <div *ngIf="userDetails | async as userDetails">
    <h1>{{userDetails.firstName}} {{userDetails.lastName}}</h1>
  </div>
</ngrx-busy>
```

```
@ViewChild(NgrxBusy) busy: NgrxBusy;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userDetails = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.userService.getUserDetails(+params.get('userId'))),
    withBusy(() => this.busy)
  );
}
```

[image: ngrx-busy]